# Database of all Mac models

Tags: mac

I need a database of all Mac models produced within the last decade (at least). Something like [EveryMac](http://www.everymac.com/) or [MacTracker](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/5968/mactracker) but as a table in SQL or a similar format, to be put into a RDBMS.

Does anybody know where I can get / buy one?

Comment: Did you contact the author of either of these applications whether they are willing to give you the data?

Comment: MacTracker's developer did not reply to my email. I also wonder where did he get his data from in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Try MacTracker. It's available in the App Store and Mac App Store. I hit enter before I finished thinking through my answer. What info do you need, Model Numbers or Model Names?

Comment: How would one extract a list of all Mac models from MacTracker?

Comment: I need model numbers, names, year and specs.

Answer (score 1):

Over at [apple-history.com](http://www.apple-history.com/downloads/) you can download the html of their Mactracker-like information.  Probably wouldn't too terribly difficult to scrape your info from it.  Below is an example of the html you can download from them...

```
<p class='specs'>Family: PowerBook</p>
<p class='specs'>Codename: Tim LC, Tim Lite, Leary, Replacements</p>
<p class='specs'>Gestalt ID: 25</p>
<p class='specs'>Minimum OS: 7.0.1</p>
<p class='specs'>Maximum OS: 7.6.1</p>
<p class='specs'>Introduced: October 1991</p>
<p class='specs'>Terminated: August 1992</p>
<br/><p class='specs'><b>Processor</b></p>
<p class='specs'>CPU: Motorola MC68030</p>
<p class='specs'>CPU Speed: 16 MHz</p>
<p class='specs'>FPU: none</p>
<p class='specs'>Bus Speed: 16 MHz</p>
<p class='specs'>Register Width: 32-bit</p>
<p class='specs'>Data Bus Width: 32-bit</p>
<p class='specs'>Address Bus Width: 32-bit</p>
<p class='specs'>ROM: 1 MB</p>
<p class='specs'>RAM Type: unique</p>
<p class='specs'>Minimum RAM Speed: 100 ns</p>
<p class='specs'>Onboard RAM: 2 MB</p>
<p class='specs'>RAM slots: 1</p>
<p class='specs'>Maximum RAM: 8 MB</p>
<p class='specs'>Level 1 Cache: 256 bytes data, 256 bytes instruction</p>
<p class='specs'>Expansion Slots: modem</p>
```

etc... etc...

Comment: I haven't found model names (like MacBookPro5,1) and model numbers (MB470LL/A) there, but this is very useful, thank you!